# class imbalance issue in multi-class classification

Tags: python, matlab, classification, svm

I need a multi-class classifier code which can work in the following class imbalance ploblem:

- class 1--> 80%
- class 2-->  7.5%
- class 3-->  6%
- class 4-->  4%
- class 5-->  2.5%

there are total of 130 instances only and there are about 5000 features for each instance.

I found a multi-class SVM code but I do not think it takes into account the class imbalance problem. Moreover, I also require to do some kind of k-fold cross-validation.

python or matlab codes will really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most people who want use SVM within MATLAB use [libSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), which has a MATLAB interface. It handles multiclass problems. 5000 features and 130 instances should be fine.

I'm not sure whether you want to treat your class imbalance using class weights/priors, or using cost-sensitive learning, but you can achieve either with a little extra work, see [here](http://www.ece.umn.edu/users/cherkass/ee4389/cost_sensitive_svm.pdf) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41190/libsvm-for-unbalanced-data) for some ideas.

k-fold cross-validation can be achieved in MATLAB using `cvpartition` from Statistics Toolbox (and is pretty straightforward to code even if you don't have Statistics Tolbox).